# Работа с тестовой выборкой без меток

Tags: машинное-обучение

Данный датасет состоит из `train`, `test` и `val` выборок для задачи бинарной классификации текстов на русском языке (поля `text` и `label`). В тестовой выборке, в отличие от остальных, отсутствует необходимый столбец с метками. Обучение планирую проводить на `fasttext`, а наличие меток для его работы, насколько понимаю, обязательно. Что в таком случае делать?

Comment: Может на `test` надо предсказать метки и куда-то загрузить полученный результат? Откуда вообще взялись эти части датасета и сама задача?

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, действительно. Только задал вопрос, и набрел на [статью](https://gosha20777.github.io/tutorial/2018/04/12/fasttext-for-windows/), где в конце как раз и описан процесс тестирования модели. Датасет - [DaNetQA](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/danetqa).